# LaTeX Warning: Citation 'aglarov02' on page 3 undefined on input line 9

Tags: bibtex, citing, warnings, overleaf, undefined

I'm new to latex and I'm using Overleaf. I encountered a warning during the introduction of my first citation. I failed to find a solution to my problem by reading tutorials and forums, although I found topics about the exact same problem.

Packages I use in my `pre.tex` file

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

reference in question in my bibliography.bib file :

```
@book{aglarov02,    address = {Makhachkala},    edition = {Yupiter},    title = {Andijcy: {Istoriko}-{etnografičeskoe} issledovanie [{Les} {Andi}: {étude} historico-ethnographique]},  shorttitle = {Les {Andis}},     author = {Aglarov, M. A.},  pages = {3},
    date = {2002}
```

Text in my main file:

```
les Andis ont été recensés comme Avars entre 1959 en 1989 (\cite[p. 3]{aglarov02}).
```

Warning content :

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation 'aglarov02' on page 3 undefined on input line
9.
```

Thanks in advance for your time and effort,

Neige

Comment: Thank you ! How do I run biber ?

Comment: @TeXnician OverLeaf does it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by replacing

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
```

...by the exact same text !

Comment: My suspicion, based on some experience of this, is that you just didn't wait long enough between edits for OverLeaf to complete all the required steps.